# Compute sums of all subsets of some words

Tags: algorithms

We have $16$ words of given length, let's say $W_1,...,W_{16}$ and I want to make an one dimensional matrix that will contain all the possible sums of $W_i$'s, for example:

$W_1,W_2,...,W_{16}$

$W_1+W_2,W_1+W_3,...,W_1+W_{16}$

$W_2+W_3,...,W_2+W_{16}$

and so on, all the pair sums...

then all the three sums

$W_1+W_2+W_3,...,W_1+W_2+W_{16}$

then all the four sums

until the sums which is all sixteen

$W_1+W_2+...+W_{16}$.

Is there a faster way than, for example, using a triple `for` to make all the possible triplet sums and in general $n$ `for` loops to make all the $n$-tuple sums?

Comment: Does the number 16 ring a bell? Do you really think this is just a C++ programming exercise? Before walking your C++ path, you are probably supposed to plan the trip. Does your course include a little bit of algorithmic complexity?

Comment: I do not know the algorithm. But I can guess a bit what it should look
like (I might be wrong). This seems much like a homework, which we are not supposed to
answer too readily (it does not help education). Another point is that
this site answers general computer science questions, not questions
about a specific programming languages, unless they are examples of a
general programming issue. So we may give you hints, as I did, but
will try to avoid straights answers on what looks like homework.

Comment: This said, as further hint, I would try to see what the problem looks
like with one or two numbers much smaller than 16. Preferably numbers
that shares one of 16 's main characteristic.

Comment: Note that generating $2^{16}$ values will take at least $2^{16}$ steps, unless you can generate multiple values in a single step. Usually it will take multiple steps per value. But you may be able to reduce the number of steps per value by cleverly reusing values computed earlier.

Comment: @FrankW I don't understand, you should still need at least $2^{16}$ steps. You don't save steps by generating multiple values at a time. What is true is that you can save the number of addition operations invoked if you reused previously computed values.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that there are much fewer than $2^{16} $ sums, you can try the following approach. Iteratively compute a sorted list of all partial sums of the first $k$ values.  Given this list for some $k$, add to all sums in the list $W_{k+1} $, and then merge the two lists like in Mergesort, removing duplicates. The total complexity should be asymptotic to the number of distinct partial sums.